# access violation from C++ to fortran array

Tags: c++, fortran

I am working on a C++-fortran mix compiling project. On the fortran side, I wrote an interface to segregate the C++ reference/pointers to fortran variables. After the fortran subroutine did their work, the interface will assign the value one-by-one to the C++ array. The problem occurred when it went back to C++ side. I can see the value of each array elements in the C++ debugger, but when I use std::cout<<arr[0]<<std::endl, it gives me the access error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x79762B8E (msvcp140d.dll) in TEST_IO.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x9C6D0014
```

I wrote a simplified test code as:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {void fort_interface(<typeName1> &par1,<typename2> *par2,....,<typeName> *output);}
int main()
{
..... //setup input parameters
float *arr = new float[N_arr]; //N_arr is big enough.

float check = 12321;
std::cout<<check<<std::endl;
/*the float variable check is independent from fort_interface, just to check the memory status*/

fort_interface(par1, par2,...,arr);

std::cout<<check<<std::endl;//exception occurs!
}
```

The same exception reported even I print out "check" that did no business with fort_interface(). At the same time, the value of "check" was 12321 in the debugger.

I wrote another toy fortran-C++ code to test how fortran play with pointers/references, everything goes well. Value can be printed, destructor works well too.

Sorry that I cannot upload the fortran-C++ interface here because it contains 100+ parameters (that's the reason why I wrote this interface to keep fortran original code intact with outside argument.) I just want to know why I can see the value in debugger but it cannot be accessed? Thank you for your help!

---

Update: The problem was solved! I passed a pointer to pointer to the fortran subroutine, which leaded the segment error. Nothing wrong about fortran-C mix compile setting. Just because of the segment error. Thank you all again!

Comment: Can you debug the value of `i` and the size of `arr` right at that line? You could also use `arr.at(i)` and catch a possible out of bounds exception (which is what looks like it's happening here).

Comment: Yes, I tried to output arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], all of them cannot be accessed. But they all have value in debugger.

Comment: You may be able to see the contents of `arr` in memory after it has been destructed; that only tells us the code executed upon `arr` destruction didn't mark that memory in any way; but that doesn't mean you can still access the contents of `arr`. I'd focus on debugging how `arr` is created, used, and destructed. Also, if you included some code in your question, somebody may spot if there's something wrong with the use of `arr`.

Comment: Astonished! Could you teach me more on that? I added some simplified code on my question. Can the array that was destructed be seen in the debugger?

Comment: From that code: 1) why are you creating an array of doubles and assigning it to a `float*`? 2) have you debugged the value of `N_arr` at the point of the array creation?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, my original code used new float[N_arr]. I checked the N_arr after initialize the array, it was correct. I found the problem was much more serious than accessibility. The whole memory was leaked. I will post update above.

Comment: Great. If you found a solution for your original problem, and you think it can be useful for other users, you can keep your original question and post an answer explaining how you fixed it.

Comment: Is the fortran interface using `BIND(C)` or `!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES` or anything like that?

Comment: Is this 32-bit or 64-bit code?  On Windows or some other operating system?  Well it's clearly Windows, from the `msvcp140d.dll in TEST_IO.exe` message, and the number of pointer digits tells me 32-bit.  Windows has multiple calling conventions on 32-bit, and you have a mismatch.  Try adding `__stdcall` to the C++ declaration of the Fortran function.

Comment: I add BIND(C) and !USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING  in the fortran subroutine. The fortran code is a static library *.lib project. I also setup the VS 2017 compiler as win32 mode. I wrote another toy code that works well under the same compiler configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see your Fortran-C++ interface, I will make a guess that might help.

When you process arrays in fortran, they are saved as columns in your memory, while C/C++ saves them as rows. which makes the interface between these two languages tricky.

For example, if you have arr[5][5] and you call the element arr[1][0] in C, the compiler will fetch the row 1 and keep it in your cache, while fortran compiler will fetch column 0 and keep it in your cache.

I hope this helps